# sequence/series limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am struggling a bit with the following two questions I got from a sister who is doing BSC in Applied Mathematics. I always try my best to help her but was stuck on these questions and so any answer and explanation is much appreciated:

Here's the question:

Decide which of the following sequences have limits when $n\rightarrow \infty$ , and find the relevant limits if they exist. In the case of $C(n)$ it is enough to show that the limit is bounded from above and below.

Sequence $B(n)$ such that
$B(0) = 0$ and $B(n) = B(n-1) + 1/2^n$ , for any positive integer $n$.

Sequence $C(n)$ such that $C(1) = 1$ and $C(n) = C(n-1) + 1/n^2$ , for any integer $n>1$

> (Hint: Use the fact $\frac{1}{n-1} -\frac{1}{n} =\frac{1}{(n(n-1))}$ with the sandwich reasoning that if $C'(n)<C(n)<C''(n)$ for all $n$, then the limit of $C(n)$ is between the limits of $C'(n)$ and $C''(n)$, if such limits exists.)

On the first question , I tried to plug some values of n and got the limit of B(n) as 1, although I am not 100% sure. But on the second one, I couldn't do much and the hint didn't help me a lot.

Comment: $B(n) \to 1$ and $C(n) \to \pi^2/6$ as $n \to \infty$. The first one is a geometric series, whereas second one is $\zeta(2)$

Comment: Please don't [repost questions which were closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3884125/446262).

Comment: For the second sequence you can use an integral to bound the sum. $C(n) = 1 + 1/2^2+1/3^2+... + 1/n^2$. We know that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx \ge 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + 1/4^2...$. Look here for details: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/IntegralTest.aspx  So we know that $1 + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx \ge 1+ 1/2^2+1/3^2+...$. The integral evaluates to 1, so we get 2 on the left side. So we know the sum is less than 2. We're also bounded below because we know the sum is greater than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

$B(0)=0$, $B(n)=B(n-1)+\frac 1 {2^{n}}$,
Thus $$B(1)= \frac 1 2,B(2)= \frac 1 2+\frac 1 4,B(3)=\frac 1 2+ \frac 1 4+\frac 1 8,\cdots B(n)= \frac1 2+\cdots \frac 1 {2^{n}} $$
Now see $$\frac{1}{2} B(n)= \frac 1 4+\frac1 8+\cdots \frac 1 {2^{n+1}}\\\implies \left(1-\frac 1 2\right)B(n)=\frac 1 2-\frac 1 {2^{n+1}}\\\implies \lim_{n\to +\infty}B(n)=1$$
$C(1)=1,C(n)=C(n-1)+\frac 1 {n^2}$

Similarly we get, $C(n)=1+\frac 1 {2^2}+\frac 1 {3^2}+\cdots +\frac 1 {n^2}$
Observe $$\frac 1 {2^2}+\frac 1 {3^2}<\frac 2 {2^2}=\frac 1 {2}\\\frac 1 {4^2}+\frac 1 {5^2}+\frac 1 {6^2}+\frac 1 {7^2}<\frac 4 {4^2}=\frac 1 {4}\\\cdots\\$$
Similarly we can say that $C_{2^{n+1}-1}<1+\frac 1 {2}+\frac 1 {4}+\cdots +\frac 1 {2^n}=B(n)+1$
Therefore $\lim C(n) <\lim(B(n))+1$, Using the fact that $C(n)$ is increasing you can conclude that $\lim C(n)$ exists.

Comment: Thanks for answering but B(n) and C(n) are 2 separate questions and in each case the question asks to not only check if limit exists but also find the limit as well(if they exist)

Comment: I am pretty sure in B.Sc. real analysis course doesn't contain finding the value of zeta (2), anyway https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem